# Convert month Fullname to month number

Tags: mysql

Is There any  built-in function in MySQL for getting Month Number for given Month Full

```
Name like 'January','March',etc.
```

I tried with `MONTH()` function  to get month number from the date like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('Apr','%b'))
```

but it is not working for Fullname like `April`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) option

```
SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('April','%M')) as Month;
```

Answer (score 2):

For matching full month names, you'll have to use the `%M` specifier in [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
%M      Month name (January..December)
```

Therefore, the following would [give this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/39566):

```
SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE('April','%M')) /* result is 4
```