# MYSQL - Get Month Number from Month Name

Tags: mysql

```
+------------+
| MonthNum   |
+------------+
| 1          |
| 2          |
| 3          |
| 4          |
| 5          |
| 6          |
| 7          |
| 8          |
| 9          |
| 10         |
| 11         |
| 12         |
+------------+
```

Query to convert Month Number to Month Name

```
mysql> select monthname(str_to_date(MonthNum,'%m')) as MonthName from MonthDemo;
```

The following is the output.

```
+-----------+
| MonthName |
+-----------+
| January   |
| February  |
| March     |
| April     |
| May       |
| June      |
| July      |
| August    |
| September |
| October   |
| November  |
| December  |
+-----------+
```

How can we do it the other way around? From Month Name to Month Number? I tried this and it isn't working

```
select monthname(str_to_date(MonthName,'%c')) as MonthName;
```

Tried the solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319926/convert-month-fullname-to-month-number)  but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build a valid date with day, month, and year components, and then use the `MONTH()` function on the resulting date, it should work.

```sql
SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(MonthName, '-01-2022'), '%M-%d-%Y')) AS MonthName;  -- 1
```

### Demo

Comment: Hello Tm. Can you explain this part, thank you so much? '-01-2022'

Comment: We are forming a full date string, e.g. `January-01-2022`, and then asking what its month number is.